# Use SQL Server recursive common table expression to get full path of all files in a folder(with subfolders)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

There is a SQL Server undocumented extended stored procedure called `xp_dirtree`, which can return all files and folders name (include subfolders) in a table format. To practice my understanding of recursive CTE, I decide to use it to get the full path of all files in a specified folder(include subfolders). However, after an hour of head scratch I still can't figure out the correct way to do it. The following code is what I have currently. Can this purpose be implemented with recursive CTE?

```
DECLARE @dir NVARCHAR(260) ;
SELECT  @dir = N'c:\temp' ;

IF RIGHT(@dir, 1) <> '\' 
    SELECT  @dir = @dir + '\' ;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dirtree', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #dirtree ;
CREATE TABLE #dirtree
(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY,
 subdirectory NVARCHAR(260),
 depth INT,
 is_file BIT
) ;

INSERT  INTO #dirtree
        EXEC xp_dirtree 
            @dir,
            0,
            1 ;

SELECT  *
FROM    #dirtree ;

WITH    files
          AS (
              SELECT    id,
                        subdirectory,
                        depth,
                        is_file, subdirectory AS path
              FROM      #dirtree
              WHERE     is_file = 1
                        AND depth <> 1
   UNION ALL
               -- ...
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    files ;
```

Suppose the xp_dirtree output is:

```
/*
id  subdirectory   depth   is_file
--- -------------- ------- -------
1   abc.mdf        1       1
2   a              1       0
3   a.txt          2       1
4   b.txt          2       1
5   a.rb           1       1
6   aaa.flv        1       1
*/
```

What I want is:

```
/*
path
------------------
c:\temp\abc.mdf
c:\temp\a\a.txt
c:\temp\a\b.txt
c:\temp\a.rb
c:\temp\aaa.flv
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want something like this:

**Test data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #dirtree
(
    id INT,
    subdirectory NVARCHAR(260),
    depth INT ,
    is_file BIT,
    parentId INT
)

INSERT INTO #dirtree(id,subdirectory,depth,is_file)
VALUES
    (1,'abc.mdf',1,1),(2,'a',1,0),(3,'a.txt',2,1),
    (4,'b.txt',2,1),(5,'a.rb',1,1),(6,'aaa.flv',1,1)
```

**Updated the parent id**

```
UPDATE #dirtree
SET ParentId = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM #dirtree
      WHERE Depth = T1.Depth - 1 AND Id < T1.Id)
FROM #dirtree T1
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        t.id,
        t.subdirectory,
        t.depth,
        t.is_file
    FROM
        #dirtree AS t
    WHERE
        is_file=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.id,
        CAST(CTE.subdirectory+'\'+t.subdirectory AS NVARCHAR(260)),
        t.depth,
        t.is_file
    FROM
        #dirtree AS t
        JOIN CTE
            ON CTE.id=t.parentId
    )
SELECT
    'c:\temp\'+CTE.subdirectory AS [path]
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.is_file=1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'c:\temp\'+t.subdirectory
FROM
    #dirtree AS t
WHERE
    is_file=1
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.id=t.id
    )
```

**Result**

```
path
---------------
c:\temp\a\a.txt
c:\temp\a\b.txt
c:\temp\abc.mdf
c:\temp\a.rb
c:\temp\aaa.flv
```

**EDIT**

Changed the tables used in the example to more look like the ones in your question

Comment: Hi Arion, I can't fully understand your code. When I test it I got the wrong answer.

Comment: The `xp_dirtree` procedure doesn't return IDs, and `depth` is therefore not a reference, it just a depth (nesting level). So you can't really join on `id = depth`.

Comment: It seems to be giving extra rows now. I think you could get rid of `UNION` in the main query and replace the `CTE`'s anchor's condition with either `parentId IS NULL` or `depth = 1`.

Comment: It does? I was thinking the recursive part would fetch the ones that has a path and the second UNION would give the files that do not have a path

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I guess I missed or mixed up something when playing with your query. The actual output is exactly what you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Almost nine years later, and unfortunately there's no out-of-the-box solution that I know of.  So I'm still looking into `xp_dirtree` and need a solution to this.

I gave Arion's answer a try and found that it was producing results.  However, with a large file system of more than 11K objects, it was running very slowly.  I saw that it was very slow even from the get go with:

```
UPDATE #dirtree
SET ParentId = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM #dirtree
      WHERE Depth = T1.Depth - 1 AND Id < T1.Id)
FROM #dirtree T1
```

Although this isn't an islands-and-gaps problem, it has some similarities and the kind of thinking with those problems has helped me here.  The code at the end is my stored procedure.  The sections have some comments as to what the code is doing.

You would use it like this:

```
exec directory 
    @root = 'c:\somepath', 
    @depth = 3, 
    @outputTable = '##results';

select * from ##results;
```

Which results in output like:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
| path                            | name       | nameNoExt  | extension | isFile | runtimeId | parentId |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
| c:\somePath\DataMovers          | DataMovers | DataMovers | NULL      | 0      | 4854      | NULL     |
| c:\somePath\DataMovers\main.ps1 | main.ps1   | main       | ps1       | 1      | 4859      | 4854     |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I had to build it this way because internally it takes xp_dirtree output and loads it into a temp table.  This prevents the ability to take the results of the proc and load them into a table outside of the proc because of the ban on nested insert-exec statements.  Don't expose @outputTable to untrusted users because it is susceptible to sql-injection.  Of course re-work the proc to avoid this however it meets your needs.

```
/*

    Summary:        Lists file directory contents.

    Remarks:        - stackoverflow.com/q/10298910
                    - This assumes that the tree is put in order where 
                      subfolders are listed right under their parent
                      folders.  If this changes in the future, a 
                      different logic will need to be implemented.

                
    Example:        exec directory 'c:\somepath', 3, '##results';
                    select * from ##results;

*/
create procedure directory
    @root nvarchar(255),
    @depth int,
    @outputTable sysname
as

-- initializations

    if @outputTable is null or not (left(@outputTable,2) = '##') or charindex(' ', @outputTable) > 0
        throw 50000, '@outputTable must be a global temp table with no spaces in the name.', 1;

    if exists (select 0 from tempdb.information_schema.tables where table_name = @outputTable) 
    begin
        declare @msg nvarchar(255) = '''tempdb.dbo.' + @outputTable + ''' already exists.'; 
        throw 50000, @msg, 1;
    end

-- fetch the tree (it doesn't have full path names)

    drop table if exists #dir;

    create table #dir (
        id int identity(1,1),
        parentId int null,
        path nvarchar(4000),
        depth int,
        isFile bit,
        isLeader int default(0),
        groupId int
    )

    insert      #dir (path, depth, isFile)
    exec        xp_dirtree @root, @depth, 1;

-- identify the group leaders (based on a change in depth)

    update  d
    set     isLeader = _isLeader
    from    (
                select  id, 
                        isLeader, 
                        _isLeader = iif(depth - lag(depth) over(order by id) = 0, 0, 1)
                from    #dir
            ) d;

-- find the parents for each leader (subsetting just for leaders improves efficiency)

    update      #dir
    set         parentId = (
                    select  max(sub.id) 
                    from    #dir sub
                    where   sub.depth = d.depth - 1 
                    and     sub.id < d.id
                    and     d.isLeader = 1
                )
    from        #dir d
    where       d.isLeader = 1;

-- assign an identifier to each group (groups being objects that are 'siblings' of the leader)

    update      d
    set         groupId = _groupId 
    from        (
                    select      *, _groupId = sum(isLeader) over(order by id)
                    from        #dir 
                ) d;

-- set the parent id for each item based on the leader's parent id

    update      d
    set         d.parentId = leads.parentId 
    from        #dir d
    join        #dir leads 
                    on d.groupId = leads.groupId 
                    and leads.parentId is not null;

-- convert the path names to full path names and calculate path parts

    drop table if exists #pathBuilderResults;

    with pathBuilder as (

        select      id, parentId, origId = id, path, pseudoDepth = depth 
        from        #dir 

        union all
        select      par.id, 
                    par.parentId,
                    pb.origId,
                    path = par.path + '\' + pb.path,
                    pseudoDepth = pb.pseudoDepth - 1
        from        pathBuilder pb
        join        #dir par on pb.parentId = par.id
        where       pb.pseudoDepth >= 2 

    )

    select      path = @root + '\' + pb.path,
                name = d.path,
                nameNoExt = iif(ext.value is null, d.path, left(d.path, len(d.path) - len(ext.value) - 1)),
                extension = ext.value,
                d.isFile,
                runtimeId = pb.origId,
                parentId = d.parentId
    into        #pathBuilderResults
    from        pathBuilder pb
    join        #dir d on pb.origId = d.id
    cross apply (select value = charindex('.', d.path)) dotPos
    cross apply (select value = right(d.path, len(d.path) - dotPos.value)) pseudoExt 
    cross apply (select value = iif(d.isFile = 1 and dotPos.value > 0, pseudoExt.value, null)) ext
    where       pb.pseudoDepth = 1
    order by    pb.origId;

-- terminate

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * into ' + @outputTable + ' from #pathBuilderResults';
    exec (@sql);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
   traverse directory tree and get back complete list of filenames w/ their paths
*/

declare
   @dirRoot varchar(255)='\\yourdir' 

declare 
   @sqlCmd    varchar(255),
   @idx       int,
   @dirSearch varchar(255)

declare @directories table(directoryName varchar(255), depth int, isfile int, rootName varchar(255),rowid int identity(1,1))

insert into @directories(directoryName, depth,isFile)
exec master.sys.xp_dirtree @dirRoot,1,1

if not exists(select * from @directories)
   return

update @directories 
set rootName = @dirRoot + '\' + directoryName

-- traverse from root directory
select @idx=min(rowId) from @directories

-- forever always ends too soon 
while 1=1
begin

   select @dirSearch = rootName 
   from @directories 
   where rowid=@idx

   insert into @directories(directoryName, depth,isfile)
   exec master.sys.xp_dirtree @dirSearch,1,1

   update @directories
   set rootName = @dirSearch + '\' + directoryName
   where rootName is null

   set @idx = @idx + 1

   -- you see what i mean don't you?
   if @idx > (select max(rowid) from @directories) or @idx is null
      break

end

  select 
    case isFile when 0 then 'Directory' else 'File' end [attribute], 
    rootName [filePath]  
  from @directories
  order by filePath
```

Answer (score -2):

Create and use sp_dirtree @Path = 'c:\', @FileOnly = 1

```
 create or alter proc sp_dirtree
       @Path      nvarchar(4000) 
     , @Depth     int = 0
     , @FileOnly  bit = 0
    as -- Dir tree with fullpath. sergkog 2018-11-14
      set nocount on
      declare @Sep nchar(1) = iif(patindex('%/%',@Path) > 0,'/','\') -- windows or posix
      set @Path += iif(right(@Path,1) <> @Sep, @Sep,'')

    declare @dirtree table(
        Id int identity(1,1) 
      , subdirectory nvarchar(4000) not null
      , depth    int  not null
      , is_file  bit  not null
      , parentId int  null
    )

    insert @dirtree(subdirectory, depth, is_file)
    exec xp_dirtree @Path, @Depth, 1

    update @dirtree
       set ParentId = (select max(id) from @dirtree where Depth = t1.Depth - 1 and Id < t1.Id)
      from @dirtree t1

    ;with cte as(
      select t.*
      from @dirtree t
      where is_file=0
     union all
      select t.id
           , convert(nvarchar(4000), cte.subdirectory+ @Sep + t.subdirectory)
           , t.depth
           , t.is_file
           , t.parentId
      from
        @dirtree t join cte on cte.id = t.parentId
     )
     select @Path + cte.subdirectory as FullPath
          , cte.is_file as IsFile
     from cte
     where cte.is_file = iif(@FileOnly = 1, 1,cte.is_file)
     union all
     select @Path + t.subdirectory
          , t.is_file
     from @dirtree t    
     where
        t.is_file = iif(@FileOnly = 1, 1,t.is_file)
        and not exists(select null from cte 
                       where cte.id=t.id
        )
    order by FullPath, IsFile
    go
```

Comment: Hi please add some description and not only post some code